# can not push data from logstash agent (on a remote server) into kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, config, remote-server

i'm trying to built a system that requires collecting data from agents and push them into kafka servers ( via logstash). After configuring kafka server.. i just tested with consumer and producer (on kafka) on local anh everything is still ok. But when i try to push data from logstash agent (on a remote server) into kafka and monitor using consumer, nothing occurs, no data pushed
Plz tell me some hints??
My config as below:

## logstash config:

```
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  kafka {
      bootstrap_servers => "public_IP_remote_server"
      topic_id => "iis"
  }
}
```

## consumer.proper (kafka server)

```
zookeeper.connect=*public_IP_remote_server*:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.id=test-consumer-group
```

## producer.proper (kafka server)

```
bootstrap.servers=*public_IP_remote_server*:9092
compression.type=none
```

## server.proper (kafka server)

```
broker.id=0
advertised.host.name=*public_IP_remote_server*
advertised.port=9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://*public_IP_remote_server*:9092
delete.topic.enable = true
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://*public_IP_remote_server*:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeezookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

## zookeeper.proper (on kafka server)

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181 
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Comment: You should also specify the port number in logstash config: `bootstrap_servers => "public_IP_remote_server:9092"`

Comment: thanks. But i tried it too...and it is still not work